# How to design a simple JSP to manage a ManyToOne Hibernate association

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

I have **Invoice** and **Supplier** hibernate entities.

One Invoice has only one supplier.

One Supplier can be linked to many invoices.

In the Invoice class, I have a supplier getter-annotated with @ManyToOne.

All works fine in the backend layer but.... what about the frontend?

I mean, my **invoices.jsp** is really simple. I have a form where you can put amount, and all invoice's data, and a `<select><option value="${supplierid}>supplier description</option></select>`.

In the POST method of my controller I receive all that data, create a new invoice, fill its properties with it and what can I do with the supplier id??

By now, I query my SupplierService for the supplier with that id (key), assign it to the "supplier" property of my brand-new invoice, and persist it to hibernate.

Is that the best practice or do you have better ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`session.load(Supplier.class, id);` is better than querying if you only want to satisfy the reference, because it wont create a roundtrip to db to get the supplier, it will return a proxy which fulfills the reference.

Comment: can you explain me better please? I'm using Spring: hibernateTemplate.load(Fornitore.class, id); it's ok? And what about the Jsp? Is it the right way to "compose" the invoice object?

Comment: what about setting a custom editor for binding the supplier property "directly":

Answer (score 0):

One other option that you have is to load and cache the suppliers, assuming this is something that doesn't change too often ("too often" needs of course to be defined, and the strategy to clear the cache too). You can then get the supplier ids from the cache before rendering the JSP and when you create the invoice on submit of the form, you can retrieve from the cache the supplier using its id.

Comment: What cache? The famous MEMCACHE?

Comment: No, you just add an attribute to the HttpSession so that you can retrieve it later (I like to create "containers" that contain a set of related data, rather than having a big mess in the session). Again, depending on your needs and volume of data, this might not be suitable to your case.

Comment: From what I know, this is for customizing request parameter binding. Not what you're looking for if I'm not mistaken.